# Illustrator: Cannot select text behind "Place" Object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I did a <kbd>File > Place</kbd> in my Illustrator document, and it is displaying the `X` frame over the thing, even after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Unfortunately, I cannot select the text box or do any of the stuff I want to do on top of the image I am trying to place.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `X` on the box means it's a Linked graphic. 
(when you placed it, in the dialog box there was a checkbox for **Link**)

You can either go to your `Links` palette and Embed the file,

or, hold <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and double-click on the graphic to open the original file in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Your placed object is simply on top of the text.  Two solutions:

1. Create a new layer > Place the graphic in the new layer > drag the layer in layer menu to below the layer with text etc. Text should now appear on top of the placed item. Also you can select (highlight) the layer you want to work on or hide the one you don't want active.
2. Select the placed object > `Object > Arrange > Send to back` (To see the extent of the "cover-up" > `View > Show Bounding Box`. 
   If any part of the lower element is free of overlapping element, clicking on it will select it and make it the active element.)